# How can I restore my backup from 18.04 in my newly installed 20.04 using Deja Dup 'Backup' app's duplicity files

Tags: 18.04, permissions, 20.04, backup, external-hdd

I recently upgraded with a flash drive my Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04

I backed up all my files on an external hard drive prior to the upgrade.

Now as I am trying to restore my data, a few problems occured.

I can't access my external hard drive altogether. There is no place to insert my password in the Backup app or in my files. I don't know how to access it and I just bought it for this upgrade.

All i want is my saved files from the previous version for schoolwork. It is all saved in the hard drive.

Any leads would be very appreciated.

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 106, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 92, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 1525, in main
    action = commandline.ProcessCommandLine(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 1175, in ProcessCommandLine
    globals.backend = backend.get_backend(args[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 225, in get_backend
    obj = get_backend_object(url_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 211, in get_backend_object
    return factory(pu)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/backends/giobackend.py", line 96, in __init__
    self.remote_file.make_directory_with_parents(None)
 gi.repository.GLib.GError: g-io-error-quark: Error creating directory /media/cosmopowiz/Seagate Backup F/Chimera24: Permission denied (14)
```

Comment: My external hard drive is password protected

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1279257/edit) to include that information, please. How you normally get to the password prompt is also important for us to know.

Comment: Sure thing, my apologies for not making it clearer right off the bat I am new to this. 

Please let me know if there is anything else I could clarify.